# Column Type not being changed from DateTime to Date? Rails 3, Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I have a migration that changes a field with existing data e_date from a datetime to a date

```
change_column :events, :e_date, :date
```

After I run the migration, I see that my data has been changed from

2012-02-15 03:30:00

to

2012-02-15 00:00:00

which indicates that the column data seems to have been attempted to be modified. But when I pull event.e_date, it still comes out as a datetime object. When I did this locally on my mysql server, it worked fine (e_date came out as a date object). Is this a postgresql problem on heroku? If so is there some kind of work around?

I tried setting e.e_date = e.e_date.to_date and it still didnt work

Comment: did you restart the Heroku application after you ran the migration? I suspect that might be the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a date column then you're not going to see the time within the data you get back as it's not being stored.  All of the time parts of the data will have been dropped.

You should see this if you're running Postgres locally, which is a very good idea.

http://www.12factor.net/dev-prod-parity